# Match single bracket (]), but ignore doubles (]])

Tags: regex

So, I'm trying to find the single bracket here in either location (note the bold single bracket):

[[ http://www.example.com/ **[** [[image:http://www.example.com/images/logo.gif]] **]** ]]

Keep in mind, I may have data like: 
[[ http://www.example.com/ **]** ]]

or:
[[ **[** http://www.example.com/ ]]

Comment: What language, what have you tried and where are your problems? Do you want to match really only a single bracket, or the content inbetween? Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if implemented use look-ahead and look-behind assertions

in perl: `/(?<!\[)\[(?!\[)/`

see http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for further information